# Can't cast JsonNull to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to copy one primitve property from one JsonObject to another

`JsonObject propertyToBeCopied = source.getAsJsonObject(propertyName);`

but I always run into this exception:

`com.google.gson.JsonNull cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject`

According to the documentation it should be possible to do the cast, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonNull.html)`JsonNull` is a `JsonElement` but not a `JsonObject` (which is itself a `JsonElement`). Using

```
JsonElement element = source.get(propertyName);
if (!(element instanceof JsonNull)) {
    JsonObject propertyToBeCopied = (JsonObject) element;
}
```

would return a `JsonElement` that is cast to `JsonObject` if it is not of the type `JsonNull`.

Comment: thank you. iam using now:

`destination.add("attribute", source.get("attribute"));`

Comment: One thing to note - you must add parenthesis around the instanceof check or the ! will not compile.

if(!(element instanceof JsonNull))...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API reference](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonNull.html), `JsonNull` derives from `JsonElement` and *not* `JsonObject`, so I don't see how that cast could ever be valid.

And have you considered using [json-simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) instead of gson?  As a general rule I find it much more convenient to work with than other json frameworks, although of course it doesn't have a lot of the extra features that gson offers.  But if all you're doing with gson is parsing json, it might be worth switching to the simpler library.

Comment: The thread is quite old, but for future reference: json-simple is not maintained anymore and has lots of outstanding bugs (e.g. handling of [BigDecimals](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues) etc) So it is not a good choice anymore

Answer (score 2):

```
JsonElement element = source.get(propertyName);
if (!(element.isJsonNull())) {
    JsonObject propertyToBeCopied = (JsonObject) element;
}
```

Which one will have better performance **isJsonNull** or using **instanceOf** operator ?

Answer (score 0):

If output do not have a Response array then there is a chance why this error is thrown.

```
JsonObject playListObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(output);

JsonArray playListInformationArray = playListObject.getAsJsonArray("Response");
```