# Deserialize with gson and null values

Tags: android, gson

I am trying to deserialize my own class with a null value. But my code doesn't work.

My json:

```
{"Text":null,"Code":0,"Title":"This is Sparta!"}
```

In my method I do the following:

```
this.setText(gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getString("Text"), String.class));
this.setTitle(gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getString("Title"), String.class));
this.setCode(gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getString("Faccode"), Integer.class))
```

I am not deserialize the whole object, because there can be a `List<T>`, too.

The error:

```
myapp W/System.err? com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 6 path $
myapp W/System.err? at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:786)
myapp W/System.err? at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:776)
myapp W/System.err? at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
myapp W/System.err? at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: You need to read about parsing with GSON first

Comment: Can you remove the solution out of your question and submit it as a proper answer? (Slightly related to Meta question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301)

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but I was getting NULLs because it was enabled that only fields marked with `@Expose` should be parsed/written, but the annotation was missing from fields.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, you must read about how to parse using gson. You can find some example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java).

Now you know how to parse, you can still have problem with null values. To solve it you must tell gson to (de)serialize `null` using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

From the `serializeNulls()` [doc](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/)

> Configure Gson to serialize null fields. By default, Gson omits all fields that are null during serialization.

**EDIT** (Not tested, based on doc)

In order to get some distinct value you can do

```
String json = ""; //Your json has a String
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

//If null, use a default value
JsonElement nullableText = jsonObject.get("Text");
String text = (nullableText instanceof JsonNull) ? "" : nullableText.getAsString();

String title = jsonObject.get("Title").toString();
int code = jsonObject.get("Code").getAsInt();
```

Otherwise if you have this pojo

```
public class MyElement {
    @SerializedName("Text")
    private String text;

    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("Code")
    private int code;
}
```

you can parse using

```
String json = ""; //Your json has a String
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
MyElement myElement = gson.fromJson(json, MyElement.class);
```

Comment: I have read alot, now. And I tried Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();, too. But didn't get it. How I have to parse it correctly? And the problem is not at serializing, but in DEserializing

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it will help. Otherwise can you provide more detail ?

Comment: Now it works. I used the JsonParser, too.  But I have JSONObject instead of JsonObject from old code.

Comment: Cool ;) `JSONObject` comes from `org.json.JSONObject` and `JsonObject` from `com.google.gson.JsonObject`. I did not think about this error.

Comment: After some testing I have some little fixes to your code. Dont use JsonElement with toString() and dont compare to null. This line works fine this.setText((nullableText instanceof JsonNull) ? "" : jsonObject.get("Text").getAsString());

Comment: `.serializeNulls()` part is irrelevant, it is only related to serialization (objects -> json), not vice versa.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem (an exception thrown on `null` value) with the following POJO:

```
public class MyElement {
    private String something;
    private String somethingElse;
    private JsonObject subEntry; // this doesn't allow deserialization of `null`!
}
```

and this code:

```
parsedJson = gson.fromJson(json, MyElement.class)
```

when `subEntry` returned by the backend was `null`.

I fixed it by changing the type of `subEntry` from `JsonObject` to `JsonElement` which is a parent class of both `JsonObject` and `JsonNull`, to allow deserialization of `null` values.

```
public class MyElement {
    private String something;
    private String somethingElse;
    private JsonElement subEntry; // this allows deserialization of `null`
}
```

To later check for null at runtime, you'd do as follows:

```
if (parsedJson.subEntry instanceof JsonNull) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379405/cant-cast-jsonnull-to-jsonobject)