# Gson change default Boolean Value to false if the field doesn't exist in json

Tags: android, gson

I have  model like  this

```
public class testModel {

    public boolean a = true;
    public Test2 test2 = new Test2();

    public class Test2 {
        public boolean b = true;
    }
}
```

and a  json like this

```
{
"test2":{}
}
```

when i parse this json with Gson

```
testModel testModel = new Gson().fromJson("{ \"test2\":{}}", testModel.class);
    Log.e("test", testModel.a + " " + testModel.test2.b);
```

and the log is:

```
E/test: true false
```

testModel.a is 'true'  but testmodel.test2.b is 'false' 
why Gson changed the default value of b while b is not exist in json?
what is the difference between b and a?

is it a Gson bug?

Comment: No.. I just tested it myself both a and b are false

Comment: @SamuelRobert what is your Gson version?

Comment: Version `2.8.0`; `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0`

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435683/deserialize-with-gson-and-null-values

Comment: @SamuelRobert I just tested with 2.8.0  but i get a true and b false.  i have same problem in a real project too.

Comment: How are you testing it? Provide the log code?

Comment: @SamuelRobert i edited my question

Comment: Seems clear enough.. Could be a bug.. Although I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @SamuelRobert I asked my question in Gson Github . I wrote the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked my question in github https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1168 and a member  answered correctly.

answer:

> TestModel has a no-arg constructor while Test2 implicitly has one that
>   takes an instance of TestModel. Mark Test2 as a static class and it will
>   work.