# GSON: Deserialize: List: How to ignore null value or convert to empty list?

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

My POJO:

```
public class Catalog {

private Integer id;
private Doc doc;
private List<Image> images;
```

If incoming json is like this:

```
{
    "catalog": {
        "id": 1,
        "doc": {
            "url": "some_url",
            "deletedAt": "2017-10-20T14:10:01.797Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-10-20T14:10:01.797Z"
        },
        "images": []
    }
}
```

> GSON success deserilaize from json to POJO. OK!

But if incoming json is like this:

```
{
    "catalog": {
        "id": 1,
        "doc": {
            "url": "some_url",
            "deletedAt": "2017-10-20T14:10:01.797Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-10-20T14:10:01.797Z"
        },
        "images": null
    }
}
```

I get errror:

```
onFailure: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 113 column 17 path $[0].some[0].catalog.images
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 113 column 17 path $[0].offers[0].catalog.images
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 113 column 17 path $[0].offers[0].catalog.images
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
```

This is because field "**images**" is null.

How to ignore (not deserialize) field when it value is **null**?

Or maybe there is another good solution? E.g. convert null to empty list.

Comment: It's not duplicate. I need deserialize (not serialize)

Comment: Have you tried initialising your list? Gson should know the difference between null and empty list and for a quick example it seemed to work.

Comment: Yes but it not help. private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

Comment: Have you checked  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435683/deserialize-with-gson-and-null-values)

Comment: I write custom gson JsonDeserializer. And check field "images" for null. And do what I need. But this is not good solution. Imagine if in incoming json has 10 null values in different nodes. So I need to create 10 custom JsonDeserializer? It's not good.