# Conversion from Json to Java Object, the int variable is by default assigned value 0, if not passed in JSON

Tags: java, json

I am using `gson.fromJson(json,class)` to convert json into a Java Object.
If I do not pass a parameter (other than an `int`) in the json, it is deserialized as `null`, but the `int` variable in the object is deserialized as 0.

So my question is, is there any annotation or any way I can use, so that if I do not pass the `int` parameter in the json, it is not deserialized as 0. Ideally, it would not show up at all in the object, but at the very least it would be `null`.

For example, the following json: `{"name":"asas"}`

If I have the above json, then using `gson.fromJson()`, will automatically deserialized `id` as 0.

Is there a way to eliminate that?

```
public class Student{

    String name;
    int id;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: So what value would you prefer the `id` to be set to, if it's not in the JSON?

Comment: it will be great if the parameter is ignored all together, but if it is not possible then null, but I think null will also not be possible. Adding any other value breaks the code

Comment: OK, let me ask that a different way.  Which of the `2^32` possible `int` values would you like to have assigned to that `int` field?  `Null` is not an `int` value.  `Ignored` is not an `int` value.  Perhaps `int` is not the data type you're looking for.

Comment: Null would be possible if you use the `Integer` type instead of `int` on your id field, otherwise as @DawoodibnKareem says the id field has to have some value

Comment: yeah, now I realized int should not be used, but its been used and I cannot change that now. So, there is no way, we can just ignore to set the value, if it is not present in the json?

Comment: No, if it has to be `int`, you'll need to set it to _something_.  The word `int` means "set aside four bytes of memory, and interpret those bytes as a number, according to certain well-understood rules".  So as soon as you say `int`, there'll always be a number in there.

Answer (score 1):

> It will be great if the parameter is ignored all together, but if it is not possible then null, but I think null will also not be possible

It's not possible to ignore the parameter because the object is defined as having the field - unlike when serializing, when you can simply not write null fields into the output JSON, deserializing requires that you *create the object*, and the object will have its fields, because they're what define that object. I.e., in order to **ignore** `id` if it's not present, you'd have to deserialize to a different object, without an `id`.

To solve your problem:

`int` cannot be null. It's a primitive. [Primitives cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047276/why-cant-primitive-data-types-be-null-in-java).

`Integer` **can** be null. Because `Integer` is an Object. Change `int id;` to `Integer id;`, and if necessary [edit your GSON config to get the behavior you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435683/deserialize-with-gson-and-null-values).

Comment: Thanks a lot, so can we do it in other way. After getting the Java object, I have to convert it into xml. Is it possible to have some annotations on the field which ignores the parameter to be included in the xml if a certain value is assigned to the field.

Comment: It depends. Basically any framework will allow you to ignore `null` values when serializing. If you want to ignore *other* values then you will probably need to use a `getter` method to serialize (look up how to do this), and make the getter return null when you want the actual value to be ignored.

Comment: And also, watch out: if you want to keep your `int` but not deserialize it to XML when it was null in the input json, **checking if it is 0** could introduce a bug: you won't know whether the input json had a null int, or it had an int that was **actually 0**

Comment: yeah, in that case I will probably go for a negative value. Thanks for the info, so what should i look/read for to return null, I am not much familiar with Gson library, can you please suggest some good link